# Facebook app request information

Tags: facebook, request, referrals

I am creating a Facebook app that uses apprequest so players can invite their frineds to play aswell. I want to be able to award points to players when people they have invited accept their invitation and start using the app too. I can retreive the request_id from the new player accepting the the invitation, is there a way I can then use this request_id to get the user id of the player that sent the apprequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might have a similar problem and doesn't want to spend hours working their way through the Facebook documentation have found this can be done quite simply with just a couple of lines of code:

```
    $ret = $facebook->api("/$request_id", 'GET');
    $inviterId = $ret['from']['id'];
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

yes http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/